# Do spiders only crawl the urls in sitemap

Tags: web, seo, web-crawler, sitemap, robots.txt

I have some restricted sections on my website for spiders to crawl.

Is it enough to refer to the sitemap.xml file that will only contain the urls I want spiders to index?

Or I should add the following meta tag to pages I would like to restrict access ?

```
<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should "disallow" those pages that you don't want spiders to crawl in robots.txt. The spiders will not even load those pages, never mind index them. Read about that here: http://www.robotstxt.org/

If you want a spider to read the pages but not index them then add the "noindex" tag, like this:

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Crawlers will most definitely crawl and index pages that are not in sitemap.xml

Comment: and if I don't want spiders to read or index a section of my website?

Comment: The robots file can stop a crawler from reading a section of your web site via folders. like "disallow /private" and it won't read any files with urls that start /private. Once you do that it doesn't matter what tags are on the pages - since the crawler can't see the tags any more.

Comment: The tags like "noindex" are there when you want crawlers to read by not index pages.

Answer (score 1):

A page does not have to be listed in an XML sitemap to be crawled. Spiders will crawl anything they can find. If you want to block a page from being crawled you need to block it using a robots.txt file.

You do not want a page to be listed in a search engine's search results you need to use the [`x-robots-tag`](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag) to explicitly prevent them from doing so. Just blocking a page from being crawled is not enough as [Google may still list a page it can't crawl if it deems that page is important and should be in its search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/why-do-google-search-results-include-pages-disallowed-in-robots-txt).

You can either use the meta tag:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Or the HTTP header:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```